# How to get data from XML node?

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I am struggling to get the data out of the following XML node. I use DocumentBuilder to parse XML and I usually get the value of a node by defining the node but in this case I am not sure how the node would be.

```
<Session.openRs status="success" sessionID="19217B84:AA3649FE:B211FF37:E61A78F1:7A35D91D:48E90C41" roleBasedSecurity="1" entityID="1" />
```

This is how I am getting the values for other tags by the tag name.

```
public List<NYProgramTO> getNYPPAData() throws Exception {
    this.getConfiguration();
    List<NYProgramTO> to = dao.getLatestNYData();
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    Document document = null;

    // Returns chunkSize
    /*List<NYProgramTO> myList = getNextChunk(to);
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(myList.size());
    myList.stream().parallel()
    .forEach((NYProgramTO nyTo) -> 
    {
        executor.execute(new NYExecutorThread(nyTo, migrationConfig , appContext, dao));
    });

    executor.shutdown();
    executor.awaitTermination(300, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    System.gc();*/

    try {
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        InputSource source = new InputSource();

        for(NYProgramTO nyProgram: to) {
            String reqXML = nyProgram.getRequestXML();
            String response = RatingRequestProcessor.postRequestToDC(reqXML, URL);
    //      dao.storeData(nyProgram);
            System.out.println(response);
            if(response != null) {
                source.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(response));
                document = builder.parse(source);

                NodeList list = document.getElementsByTagName(NYPG3Constants.SERVER);
                for(int iterate = 0; iterate < list.getLength(); iterate++){
                    Node node = list.item(iterate);

                    if(node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                        Element element = (Element) node;
                        nyProgram.setResponseXML(response);
                        nyProgram.setFirstName(element.getElementsByTagName(NYPG3Constants.F_NAME).item(0).getTextContent());
                        nyProgram.setLastName(element.getElementsByTagName(NYPG3Constants.L_NAME).item(0).getTextContent());
                        nyProgram.setPolicyNumber(element.getElementsByTagName(NYPG3Constants.P_NUMBER).item(0).getTextContent());
                        nyProgram.setZipCode(element.getElementsByTagName(NYPG3Constants.Z_CODE).item(0).getTextContent());
                        nyProgram.setDateOfBirth(element.getElementsByTagName(NYPG3Constants.DOB).item(0).getTextContent());
                        nyProgram.setAgencyCode(element.getElementsByTagName(NYPG3Constants.AGENCY_CODE).item(0).getTextContent());
                        nyProgram.setLob(element.getElementsByTagName(NYPG3Constants.LINE_OF_BUSINESS).item(0).getTextContent());

                        if(element.getElementsByTagName(NYPG3Constants.SUBMISSION_NUMBER).item(0) != null){
                            nyProgram.setSubmissionNumber(element.getElementsByTagName(NYPG3Constants.SUBMISSION_NUMBER).item(0).getTextContent());
                        } else {
                            nyProgram.setSubmissionNumber("null");
                        }
```

I need to get the value for sessionId. What I want to know is the node, I am sure it can't be .I am retrieving the values via tag names so what would be the tag name in this case?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Post the code you use por parsing and getting data from the xml file, please

Comment: @nlopex. I've edited my question and posted some code on how I am getting the values. I get the values by the tag name but how can I get the sessionId.

Comment: check out my answer! Hope it's helpful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider using XPath. At least for me, is so much easy to use and, in your case, in order to get sessionID you could try something like this:

```
XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
String expression = "/Session.openRs/@sessionID";

String sessionID = xPath.evaluate(expression,document);
```

You can obtain 'document' like this:

```
Document document  = builder.newDocumentBuilder();
```

Hope this can help!!

Comment: I guess I can only get the the sessionID using XPATH. Thanks nlopex